# Write a join query for get Project information

Tags: sql-server, join, foreign-keys

I need to write a join query for get project details(As below image). My requirement is project manager needs to get list of `developer,WorkingHours,overtime` for specific project his assigned.My database table structure as follows. Can I achieve my requirement using this structure? or need to be any changes in table this structure?

```
CREATE TABLE Developer (
    DeveloperID int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    Name varchar(255),
    Email varchar(255),
    Mobile varchar(255),
    Primary key(DeveloperID)
);

CREATE TABLE Manager (
    ManagerID int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    Name varchar(255),
    Email varchar(255),
    Mobile varchar(255),
    Primary key(ManagerID)
);
```

This is my requirement,can I get this output using this table structure using `SQL Server`? if yes, How?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry I forget to add it, `SQLServer` please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on most DBMS:

```
SELECT m.Name manager,
    p.Name project,
    d.Name developer,
    t1.allhours,
    t1.allovertime,
    100.0 * (t1.allhours + t1.allovertime) / t2.totalhours contribution
FROM Project p
LEFT JOIN Manager m ON m.ManagerID = p.ManagerID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT dp.DeveloperID, dp.ProjectID, SUM(dp.WorkingHours) allhours, SUM(dp.Overtime) allovertime
    FROM DevProj dp
    GROUP BY dp.DeveloperID, dp.ProjectID
) t1 ON t1.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
LEFT JOIN Developer d ON d.DeveloperID = t1.DeveloperID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT dp2.ProjectID, SUM(dp2.WorkingHours + dp2.Overtime) totalhours
    FROM DevProj dp2
    GROUP BY dp2.ProjectID
) t2 ON t2.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
WHERE m.Name = 'Manager A'
ORDER BY p.Name;
```

This returns a table like `Manager | Project | Developer | Hours | Overtime | Contribution`. One row for every developer on all projects.

Comment: What is contribution related to? DevProj I assume? Is it a string, you want to "summarize" (concatenate) for each developer? Is it the `Descriptions` column?

Comment: I updated my answer. Note: This SQL is not tested, since I don't have a SQL-server instance to run it. If the second subquery fails try `SUM(dp2.WorkingHours) + SUM(dp2.Overtime)`

Comment: It should work with `100.0 * (t1.allhours + t1.allovertime) / t2.totalhours contribution`. Probably due to datatypes and rounding

Comment: I don't think you need to change anything. It runs on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b26d6/2